# accessing element belonging to a different form in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I need to access a `textbox` belonging to a different form in a JSP, using javascript. how is this possible? I need to access the element from a different form in jsp..

```
$('#fsubmit1').click(function () {
  var tmp = new Date();
  var month = tmp.getMonth() + 1;
  $('#timestamp').val(tmp.getFullYear() + 
                      ':' + month + ':' + 
                      tmp.getDate() + ':' + 
                      tmp.getHours() + ':' + 
                      tmp.getMinutes());
  document.myform1.submit();
});
```

In the above function, i need to access `timestamp` element, which is a textbox belonging to a form called `myform` and populate it. how is this possible?

Comment: You can use its id and `val()`. What error/output you are getting?

Comment: i can use its i.d if it is of the same form, but it belongs to a different form. the result is that i am unable to populate the above textbox, which belongs to a different form, from the above function

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to access it with `document.forms["myform"].getElementById("timestamp").value = "yourNewValue"`

if you have a multiline textbox i think you need `.text` instead of `.value`

Comment: i am unable to populate the textbox from my function using the above code snippet

Comment: nope. the `fsubmit1` element in the JSP refers to a hyperlink. will this be a problem? is my function getting called successfully?

Comment: <form name="myform1" action="ldbrsubmit1" method="post"><input name='timestamp3' id='timestamp3' /><a href="#" id="fsubmit1">submit</a></form>

Comment: how should i able to tell whether your function is call if you do not show the code that attempts to call it?

Comment: in the code you just postied your link doesn merely scroll to the top of the page... do you modify that link in any way? why don't you place an alert in your function to see if it gets called?

Comment: tried putting an alert box, and the alert box dint come up. so i think the problem is that my javascript fuction is not getting called upon the click of the hyperlink

Comment: then i suggest you fix your link first

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are accessing an element in a different form. Are these two forms going to be rendered in the same page in the browser?

JavaScript can only access elements in the same page in the browser. You could, for example, include the JSP with the form containing myform1 in the JSP containing the JavaScript code you posted.

Comment: yes, the element belongs to the same page. both the forms are rendered in the same page in the browser.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the form `myform1`?